# Go server : get non-empty net.Conn

Tags: go, network-programming, server

I have server with several net.Conn. How can I get list of net.Conn which have unreaded messages (without using active waiting) ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can.

If you try to read from the `net.Conn` with its `Read` method, it will block until there is data. So just start a goroutine for each `net.Conn`, and read from it in the goroutine.

The example in the net package's documentation does exactly that: https://pkg.go.dev/net#example-Listener